Prove that $f$ has an analytic antidertivative in $\Omega$ if and only if $\int_{\gamma_1}f(z)dz = 0.$
Let $f$ be analytic in a bounded connected domain $\Omega$ and continuous in the closure of $\Omega$. Suppose that the boundary of $\Omega$ consists of two disjoint smooth simple closed curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$. Prove that $f$ has an analytic antiderivative in $\Omega$ if and only if $\int_{\gamma_1}f(z)dz = 0$.
My Attempt:
I won't write all the details as it's somewhat tedious. Though, Jordan's Closed Curve Theorem gives that each $\gamma_i$ divides the plane into two open connected sets $E_j, I_j$ for $j = 1,2$ where $E_j$ is unbounded and $I_j$ is bounded.  I can show wlog $I_1 \supset I_2$ and $\Omega = I_1 \backslash \overline{I_2}$.
My desire hereafter is to show that there is a closed curve $\eta_1$ homotopic to $\gamma_1$ lying entirely within $\Omega$; then if $F' = f$, we have that $\int_{\eta_1}f(z)dz = F(\eta_1(1))-F(\eta_1(0)) = 0.$ Uniform convergence should finish off this direction.
As for the other direction, I am thoroughly lost.
I have also thought that perhaps it is possible to show that $\Omega$ must be conformally equivalent to an annulus and so it would suffice to solve the problem only for annuli; however, I don't know that such equivalence holds.

Let $a$ and $b$ be points of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ respectively such that the line segment $[a,b]$ does not intersect $\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2$.  $\Omega \backslash [a,b]$ is simply connected, so $f$ has an antiderivative $F$ defined there.  By Morera's theorem it suffices to show $F$ can be extended continuously to $\Omega$, i.e. that the limit of $F$ at any point $c$ of $(a,b)$ exists. This is true because if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are points of $\Omega$ near $c$ with $z_1$ on one side of $[a,b]$ and $z_2$ on the other, we can write $F(z_2) - F(z_1) = \int_\gamma f(z)\; dz$ where $\gamma$ goes in straight lines from $z_1$ to $c$, then to $a$, then around $\gamma_1$ (forward or backward) to $a$ again, then on straight lines to $c$ and then to $z_2$.  The result is small because $\int_{\gamma_1} f(z)\; dz = 0$ and the segments from $c$ to $a$ and from $a$ to $c$ cancel out.

Is there an easy way to show that $\Omega \backslash [a,b]$ is simply connected? Intuitively I see this immediately; however, I have been struggling to do this problem in a purely rigorous manner.
